# Correction of an algorithm for String analysis

Tags: java, string, algorithm, parsing, text-parsing

I need to create an algorithm that, given a `string` and a `pattern` respected by it, extracts information out of the string.

To be more exact, I defined an object called `StringPattern` that is composed by a succession of three elements:

- *Labels*, i.e. `String`s that starts with a `[` and ends with a `]` (example: `[nameShow]`, `[season]`, `[episode]`);
- *Quotes*, or fixed `String`s;
- *Free Strings*, or a `String` of any length, including the void one, represented by the character `*`.

The content I want to extract is the value of the *Labels* in the `string`. For example: the string `Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4` respects the pattern `*s[season]e[episode] *.mp4`, the value of the label `[season]` is `02` and the value of `[episode]` is `18`.

---

My first solution is as follows:

0. Assumption: an acceptable `StringPattern` is such that every *Label* is surrounded by *Quotes*.
1. If the *Label* which value I am seeking is the first component of the `StringPattern`, return `string.substring(0, string.indexOf(pattern.secondComponent()))`
2. If the *Label* which value I am seeking is the second component of the `StringPattern`, return `string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(pattern.secondButLastComponent(), string.length()));`
3. If the *Label* is in the middle of the `pattern`, do the following:

   1. Compute the index of the *Label* among the components of the `pattern` and save it in the variable `indexOfLabel`
   2. If the *Label* is not among the components of the `pattern`, return `null`.
   3. Otherwise return the substring between the end of the previous component (i.e. `string.indexOf(pattern.component(indexOfLabel-1)) + pattern.component(indexOfLabel-1).length()` ) and the start of the next one (i.e. `string.indexOf(pattern.component(indexOfLabel+1))` )

I realized this algorithm is wrong. In the example provided, when seeking the value of the *Label* `[season]` the algorithm correctly returns what is between the substrings  `s` and `e`. However, when seeking the value of the *Label* `[episode]`, the algorithm will identify as the "previous component" the `e` contained in the word `Rebels`, thus returning `ls` as supposed "value".

---

I initially thought to use the relative position of the *Label*s in the `StringPattern` as an advantage. The pseudocodes follows:

3. If the *Label* (that I will now call `searchedLabel`) is in the middle of the `pattern`, do the following:

   - Sets the variable `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString` and `indexOfCurrentLabel` at `-1`;
   - For each *Label* in the `StringPattern` before the one we are interested in:

     1. Search in the `string` the first occurrence of the *Quote* that preceedes the current *Label* that is after `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString` and save this value in `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString`
   - Now the variable `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString` stores the index of the *Quote* before the first *Label* that preceedes `searchedLabel`
   - Search in the `string` the first occurrence (after the index `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString`) of the *Quote* after the first *Label* that preceedes `searchedLabel`, and store it in `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString`
   - Now the variable `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString` should store the start index of the quote after the first *Label* that preceedes `searchedLabel`
   - Search (at last!) in the `string` the first occurrence (after the index `indexOfPreviousQuoteInString`) of the *Quote* before `searchedLabel` and store it in `indexOfQuoteBeforeThisLabel`
   - Search in the `string` the first occurrence (after the index `indexOfQuoteBeforeThisLabel`) of the *Quote* after `searchedLabel` and store it in `indexOfQuoteAfterThisLabel`
   - The value of `searchedLabel` is the sub`string` between the indexes [`indexOfQuoteBeforeThisLabel+QuoteBeforeThisLabel.length()`, `indexOfQuoteAfterThisLabel`).

I realized it does not work. To see it, swap the position of the season and episode part in the string and pattern both. Now the string is `Star Wars Rebels e18s02 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4` and the pattern it respects is `*e[episode]s[season] *.mp4`. Since `[episode]` is the first *Label* in the `StringPattern` (but not the first component), I have no previous *Label* to rely on: the algorithm will return the first substring between `e` and `s`, i.e. `bel`. Plus, it is horribly complicated.

Now I ask for help. I am pretty sure there is a nifty trick that would help me solve this problem in few, easy-to-understand lines of code (personal experience...), but I do not see. Any help? New perspectives? Hints?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Did you consider using regular expressions (Java classes Pattern and Matcher) instead of your own pattern syntax? Regex syntax is a bit tricky, but supports named groups (what you call Labels) and of course, various wildcards. And using it in Java code is a no-brainer.

Comment: Yep... use Regex.  You don't give it enough hints and it will be a lot more effort than to come up with a good regex - i.e. ^[ A-Za-z0-9]+ e(?<season>[0-9]+)s(?<episode>[0-9]+) - .+$

Comment: I wanted the user to specify a pattern himself with a syntax as simple as possible, so a self-made class is useful in that regard.

Comment: As for the Regex... admittedly I didn't know they existed before now. @John John Why did you bounded the *labels* with round parentesys preceeded by an interrogative point in your translation?

Comment: Round parenthesis are called capture groups.  ([0-9]+) will capture 1 or more digits in the range 0-9.  The ?<text> is to give the capture group a name.  Unnamed capture groups are referred to by number - i.e. $1 or \1 depending on system, whereas named capture groups can be referred to by name.