# Java Regex - Probable error while defining capturing groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Pseudo-Sequel of [Correction of an algorithm for String analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383313/correction-of-an-algorithm-for-string-analysis). Reading the link is unnecessary to understand the problem, but it gives it context.

My goal is to extract the content of a capture group from a string that satisfies a regex. My problem is (apparently) that I do not identify/define correctly the capture groups.

In the example provided below, the regex is `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9] s(?<season>[A-Za-z0-9])e(?<episode>[A-Za-z0-9]) [A-Za-z0-9].mp4`. This (in theory) should be a regex satisfied by any string that has:

- A random (even void) prefix;
- Followed by the string  `s`;
- Followed by a number of alphanumeric characters (named group `season`);
- Followed by the string `e`;
- Followed by a number of alphanimeric characters (named group `episode`);
- Followed by the string   (a simple empty space);
- Followed by a random (even void) string;
- Followed by the string `.mp4`;

In theory the small snippet of code below should sift the input string (`Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4`) and recognize `02` as the value of the named group `season` and `18` as the value of `episode`. Instead I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` error message. Worst of it, after modifying the code so it would show the named group's names, it seems there are *no* named group. I am quite baffled.

What am I doing wrong? Is a problem of defining the named groups? Of recalling them in the method `matcher.group(...)`? Is the regex written wrong?

Fair warning: this is my first experience with Java regex, so there may be multiple problems.

---

The code:

```
String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9] s(?<season>[A-Za-z0-9])e(?<episode>[A-Za-z0-9]) [A-Za-z0-9].mp4";
String string = "Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4";
        
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
System.out.println("\t\t pattern: " + pattern.toString() + "\n\t\t Named groups: ");
for(int i=0 ; i<matcher.groupCount() ; i++)
    System.out.println("\t\t\t Group " + i + "-th: " + matcher.group(i));
        
System.out.println("Season value: " + matcher.group("season"));
System.out.println("\t Episode value: " + matcher.group("episode"));
```

Comment: You are not repeating the character classes, and using the anchor `^` like this will prevent the pattern to match as in the example string there is text before to match. Try `^.*?[A-Za-z0-9]{2} s(?<season>[A-Za-z0-9]+)e(?<episode>[A-Za-z0-9]+) - .*[A-Za-z0-9]\.mp4$` https://regex101.com/r/2l6ik6/1

Comment: You never allowed `matcher` to actually *search* for part of text which could match the regex by invoking its `find()` method, nor check if regex actually `matches()` *entire* string (depending on your intention). Please take a few steps back and read java tutorial about how to use *regex* engine in that language.

Comment: Example using matcher.find  https://ideone.com/eTfLm2

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No match Found" when using matcher's group method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674268/no-match-found-when-using-matchers-group-method)

Answer (score 0):

**Some alternative regex for extracting season and episode from a String**

**Alternative 1 - defining group name:**

```
"\\w+\\s+s(?<season>\\d+)e(?<episode>\\d+).*\\w+\\.mp4"
```

**See Alternative 1 regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4";

    // From the input the following is matched: 'Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4'
    String regex = "\\w+\\s+s(?<season>\\d+)e(?<episode>\\d+).*\\w+\\.mp4";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    // The condition have to be true before using "matcher.group()",
    // or 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found' will be thrown.
    if(matcher.find()) { 
        // Output: 'Season value:  02'
        System.out.println("Season value:\t" + matcher.group("season"));
        // Output: 'Episode value: 18'
        System.out.println("Episode value:\t" + matcher.group("episode"));
    }
}
```

**Alternative 2 - no group name, matching whole input:**

```
"^\\S+\\s.*?\\ss(\\S+)e(\\S+).*\\S+\\.mp4"
```

**In context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4";

    // From the input the following is matched: 'Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4'
    String regex = "^\\S+\\s.*?\\ss(\\S+)e(\\S+).*\\S+\\.mp4";
    // MULTILINE due to Boundary matcher '^'
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);

    // The condition have to be true before using "matcher.group()",
    // or 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found' will be thrown.
    if(matcher.find()) {
        String season = matcher.group(1);
        String episode = matcher.group(2);
        // Output: 'Season value:  02'
        System.out.println("Season value:\t" + season);
        // Output: 'Episode value: 18'
        System.out.println("Episode value:\t" + episode);
    }
}
```

**Alernative 3:**

```
"^\\w+\\s.+?\\ss(?<season>\\w+)e(?<episode>\\w+).*\\w+\\.mp4"
```

**In context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4";

    // From the input the following is matched: 'Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4'
    String regex = "^\\w+\\s.+?\\ss(?<season>\\w+)e(?<episode>\\w+).*\\w+\\.mp4";
    // MULTILINE due to Boundary matcher '^'
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);

    // The condition have to be true before using "matcher.group()",
    // or 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found' will be thrown.
    if(matcher.find()) {
        // Output: 'Season value:  02'
        System.out.println("Season value:\t" + matcher.group("season"));
        // Output: 'Episode value: 18'
        System.out.println("Episode value:\t" + matcher.group("episode"));
    }
}
```

**Alternative 4:**

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s.+?s(?<season>[A-Za-z0-9]+)e(?<episode>[A-Za-z0-9]+).*[A-Za-z0-9]\\.mp4"
```

**In context**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4";

    // From the input the following is matched: 'Star Wars Rebels s02e18 - The Forgotten Droid.mp4'
    String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s.+?s(?<season>[A-Za-z0-9]+)e(?<episode>[A-Za-z0-9]+).*[A-Za-z0-9]\\.mp4";
    // MULTILINE due to Boundary matcher '^'
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);

    // The condition have to be true before using "matcher.group()",
    // or 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found' will be thrown.
    if(matcher.find()) {
        // Output: 'Season value:  02'
        System.out.println("Season value:\t" + matcher.group("season"));
        // Output: 'Episode value: 18'
        System.out.println("Episode value:\t" + matcher.group("episode"));
    }
}
```

There are many ways to match the input to extract the season and episode.
Here is a list of Java's "Class Pattern" for more options:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html